# Trouble making rviz plugin

Tags: ros, c++, catkin-make, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm learning how to [make a simple rviz plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin) and I'm running into some trouble. The errors sound like maybe some includes are missing but I'm not sure. What is the next logical troubleshooting step after this?

```
 $ make_catkin
make_catkin: command not found
jackson@jackson-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/jackson/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jackson/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/jackson/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 50%] [100%] Built target polygon_plugins
Building CXX object pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/src/polygon_loader.cpp.o
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:6:26: error: ‘polygon_base’ was not declared in this scope
   pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("pluginlib_tutorials_", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
                          ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:6:54: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("pluginlib_tutorials_", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
                                                      ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:6:67: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
   pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("pluginlib_tutorials_", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
                                                                   ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:6:122: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
   pluginlib::ClassLoader<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> poly_loader("pluginlib_tutorials_", "polygon_base::RegularPolygon");
                                                                                                                          ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:6:122: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:10:51: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> class boost::shared_ptr’
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> triangle = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Triangle");
                                                   ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:10:51: error:   expected a type, got ‘polygon_base’
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:10:62: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> triangle = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Triangle");
                                                              ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:10:76: error: request for member ‘createInstance’ in ‘poly_loader’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> triangle = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Triangle");
                                                                            ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:11:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     triangle->initialize(10.0);
             ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:13:51: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> class boost::shared_ptr’
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> square = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Square");
                                                   ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:13:51: error:   expected a type, got ‘polygon_base’
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:13:60: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> square = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Square");
                                                            ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:13:74: error: request for member ‘createInstance’ in ‘poly_loader’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     boost::shared_ptr<polygon_base::RegularPolygon> square = poly_loader.createInstance("polygon_plugins::Square");
                                                                          ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:14:11: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     square->initialize(10.0);
           ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/pluginlib/class_loader.h:38:0,
                 from /home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:1:
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:16:45: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     ROS_INFO("Triangle area: %.2f", triangle->area());
                                             ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:16:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
     ROS_INFO("Triangle area: %.2f", triangle->area());
     ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:17:41: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
     ROS_INFO("Square area: %.2f", square->area());
                                         ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:17:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
     ROS_INFO("Square area: %.2f", square->area());
     ^
make[2]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/src/polygon_loader.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247554/trouble-making-rviz-plugin/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-08**:
If you don't include your `package.xml` and your `CMakeLists.txt` (please **without** all the comments), it's going to be difficult to help you.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-11-08**:
Great point @gvdhoorn. Fortunately I found my error because I was able to respond to this. I'm willing to bet you would have quickly noticed what I eventually found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I needed to add `include_directories(include)` to my `CMakeLists.txt`

Also, I found that in the `CMakeLists.txt` already with some notes about it. What I needed to do was uncommented it and then `catkin_make` ran 100%.

As far as I can tell, they forgot to mention this step in the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0